# Visual Studio : These projects are out of date. Where does Visual Studio get its information from?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Good morning,
I'm working with Visual Studio Express 2013.
I have two solutions, each of them consisting of different Visual Studio projects.
Some of those projects are shared between the two solutions.

When I re-build one solution and I would like to do run the other solution, I always get the warning message "These projects are out of date: ..." (mentioning all the shared projects).

Sometimes this is interesting (it happens that a project (not a shared one) has been altered without my knowledge), but sometimes it's really annoying (I always need to rebuild the projects which are shared between both projects).

Does anybody know where Visual Studio is getting the information, which generates the mentioned warning message? (This could allow me to write a simple batch script, executing some "touch" commands, in order to avoid needless rebuilds)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can also be caused by a subtle change to a project.  If a header file was deleted from a folder, and, **not** removed from the project, Visual Studio will think it needs to rebuild the project.  For VS2010, the following Microsoft [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2013/03/12/alwayscreate-forces-project-to-be-re-built/) highlights the problem and the resolution.  I would suggest you eliminate this possibility by checking that all files in the project(s) actually do exist.